# Remove characters in specific lines in notepad++

Tags: registry, notepad++

I am really new to notepad++ and I tried to search for a solution here but I didn't understand much. I am trying to edit registry files for windows.

I have over a thousand lines containing e.g

```
"CanonicalName"="{8133CB32-451F-4A9F-9B90-F6F80FCE6348}"
"CanonicalName"="{af01f534-9beb-4d8c-b729-ddf4e2579f31}"
"CanonicalName"="{d577c470-5769-4467-9e71-a14b4a659aa7}"
```

etc...

I want to delete all the characters including the brackets so that

```
"CanonicalName"="{8133CB32-451F-4A9F-9B90-F6F80FCE6348}"
```

becomes

```
"CanonicalName"=""
```

And I want this for all similar lines. Problem is that the 32 characters between the brackeets are different for every line. How can I make notepad++ delete every character including the brackets for all the lines containing "CanonicalName"=  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can easily do this using regex replacements.

Replace all `"CanonicalName"="[^"]*"` with `"CanonicalName"=""`.

I've also included a screenshot [image: link]

Comment: Thanks. That's a perfect solution! You saved me some time there!

Comment: @FasilSeyoum Please consider marking my reply as answer. This will help others who may come seeking solution to a similar problem.

Comment: I am actually not sure how to do that. I tried to vote up, but that requires 15 in reputation.